# Google Map not Displayed , Cannot get my LatLong

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, latitude-longitude, android-gps

I need help. I have already set up Google Console in the right way, the right API and the right package name and SHA-1 for restricting usage in Android apps and I can see the green checkmark. In other words it worked before, but now the map in Google Map gone, just showing logo, my button and still can detect my LatLong.

My other problem is my Google Map can't show LatLong, my location button, and can't use mark if I turn off GPS. I need to turn ON the GPS outside of the activity. Even I make refresh button but still I need to turn on GPS outside of activity (like before get inside the map activity).

Here is my MapActivity:

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
  
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private FloatingActionButton fabDone, fabRefresh;
    private Location currentLocation;
    private boolean gps_enabled = false;
    private boolean network_enabled = false;
    private Double MyLat, MyLong;
    private String kode;
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 101;
    Marker incidentMarker;
    Geocoder geo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        kode = intent.getStringExtra("kode");

        
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Map");

        fabDone     = findViewById(R.id.fab_done);
        fabRefresh  = findViewById(R.id.fab_refresh);
        
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        geo = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());

        turnGPSOn();
        fetchLocation();

        fabRefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener locListener = new MyLocationListener();

        try {
            gps_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        try {
            network_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.


            return;
        }

        if (gps_enabled) {
            locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
            currentLocation = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        }

        if(network_enabled && currentLocation==null){
            locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
            currentLocation = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        }

        if (currentLocation != null) {

            MyLat = currentLocation.getLatitude();
            MyLong = currentLocation.getLongitude();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(MyLat, MyLong);
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 12.0f));

        } else {
            Location loc= getLastKnownLocation(this);
            if (loc != null) {

                MyLat = loc.getLatitude();
                MyLong = loc.getLongitude();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(MyLat, MyLong);
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 12.0f));
            }
        }

       
        locManager.removeUpdates(locListener);

        try {
            mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
                    if (incidentMarker != null)
                        incidentMarker.remove();
                    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Incident Location");
                    try {
                        Address address = geo.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 2).get(0);
                        String addressLine = address.getAddressLine(0); // If any additional                       

                        String snippets = addressLine;
                        Log.d("MAP", snippets);
                        options.snippet(snippets);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    incidentMarker = mMap.addMarker(options);
                    incidentMarker.showInfoWindow();
                }
            });


            fabDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   
                    if (incidentMarker == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Points the incident location using Long Click!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    } else {

                        if (kode.equals("1")) {

                            Intent intent = new Intent(MapActivity.this, AddReportActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("address", incidentMarker.getSnippet());
                            intent.putExtra("latitude", incidentMarker.getPosition().latitude);
                            intent.putExtra("longitude", incidentMarker.getPosition().longitude);

                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();//finishing activity

                        } else if (kode.equals("2")) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MapActivity.this, EditReportActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("address", incidentMarker.getSnippet());
                            intent.putExtra("latitude", incidentMarker.getPosition().latitude);
                            intent.putExtra("longitude", incidentMarker.getPosition().longitude);

                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();//finishing activity
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

        if (gps_enabled && network_enabled && currentLocation!=null){
            MyLat = currentLocation.getLatitude();
            MyLong = currentLocation.getLongitude();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(MyLat, MyLong);
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 12.0f));
        } else if (gps_enabled && network_enabled && currentLocation==null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Location can't be found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please turn ON the GPS.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }


    private void fetchLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE);
            return;
        }
        Task<Location> task = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if (location != null) {
                    currentLocation = location;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), currentLocation.getLatitude() + "" + currentLocation.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fama_map);
                    assert supportMapFragment != null;
                    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(MapActivity.this);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    fetchLocation();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.map_options, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
            }
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }

    public static Location getLastKnownLocation(Context context) {
        Location location = null;
        @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") LocationManager locationmanager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService("location");
        List list = locationmanager.getAllProviders();
        boolean i = false;
        Iterator iterator = list.iterator();
        do
        {
            //System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------");
            if(!iterator.hasNext())
                break;
            String s = (String)iterator.next();
            
            if(i != false && !locationmanager.isProviderEnabled(s))
                continue;
            
            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission") Location location1 = locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(s);
            if(location1 == null)
                continue;
            if(location != null)
            {
                
                float f = location.getAccuracy();
                float f1 = location1.getAccuracy();
                if(f >= f1)
                {
                    long l = location1.getTime();
                    long l1 = location.getTime();
                    if(l - l1 <= 600000L)
                        continue;
                }
            }
            location = location1;
            
            i = locationmanager.isProviderEnabled(s);
            // System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------");
        } while(true);
        return location;
    }

    public void turnGPSOn(){
        try
        {

            String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);


            if(!provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is disabled
                final Intent poke = new Intent();
                poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
                poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
                poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
                sendBroadcast(poke);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
    // Method to turn off the GPS
    public void turnGPSOff(){
        String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

        if(provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is enabled
            final Intent poke = new Intent();
            poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
            poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
            poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
            sendBroadcast(poke);
        }
    }

    // turning off the GPS if its in on state. to avoid the battery drain.
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        turnGPSOff();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think this will help you. First see the package name is same you register on [console](https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_android_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_ANDROID&r=6A:18:BC:36:53:83:8A:2B:E4:B4:00:00:DC:D4:F8:D9:C9:A1:EA:CE%3Bcom.orbitalsonic.googlemapproject)

**build.gradle**

```
  // google map services
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.1'
    // location play services
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
    // dexter runtime permissions
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0'
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

**Java MapsActivity.java**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    TextView txtLocationResult;
    TextView txtUpdatedOn;
    Button btnStartUpdates;
    Button btnStopUpdates;

    // location last updated time
    private String mLastUpdateTime;

    // location updates interval - 10sec
    private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 10000;

    // fastest updates interval - 5 sec
    // location updates will be received if another app is requesting the locations
    // than your app can handle
    private static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 3000;

    private static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 100;


    // bunch of location related apis
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    private SettingsClient mSettingsClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private LocationSettingsRequest mLocationSettingsRequest;
    private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;
    private Location mCurrentLocation;
    private MarkerOptions marker;
    private ArrayList<LatLng> locList;

    // boolean flag to toggle the ui
    private Boolean mRequestingLocationUpdates;

    private String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        locList = new ArrayList();
        marker = new MarkerOptions();

        initViews();
        initValues();
        onClickMethod();

        // restore the values from saved instance state
        restoreValuesFromBundle(savedInstanceState);
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;


        LatLng islamabad = new LatLng(33.684422, 73.047882);
        mMap.setMinZoomPreference(15.0f);
        mMap.setMaxZoomPreference(20.0f);
        marker.position(islamabad);
        mMap.addMarker(marker);
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(islamabad, 17F));
    }

    private void mapDrawLocation(LatLng loc){

        mMap.clear();

        marker.position(loc);
        mMap.addMarker(marker);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 17F));


    }

    private void initViews(){
        txtLocationResult = findViewById(R.id.location_result);
        txtUpdatedOn = findViewById(R.id.updated_on);
        btnStartUpdates = findViewById(R.id.btn_start_location_updates);
        btnStopUpdates = findViewById(R.id.btn_stop_location_updates);
    }

    private void onClickMethod(){
        btnStartUpdates.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            startLocationButtonClick();
        });

        btnStopUpdates.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            stopLocationButtonClick();
        });
    }

    private void initValues() {
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        mSettingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);

        mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                // location is received
                mCurrentLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());

                updateLocationUI();
            }
        };

        mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
        builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
        mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build();
    }

    /**
     * Restoring values from saved instance state
     */
    private void restoreValuesFromBundle(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("is_requesting_updates")) {
                mRequestingLocationUpdates = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("is_requesting_updates");
            }

            if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("last_known_location")) {
                mCurrentLocation = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("last_known_location");
            }

            if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("last_updated_on")) {
                mLastUpdateTime = savedInstanceState.getString("last_updated_on");
            }
        }

        updateLocationUI();
    }


    /**
     * Update the UI displaying the location data
     * and toggling the buttons
     */
    private void updateLocationUI() {
        if (mCurrentLocation != null) {
            txtLocationResult.setText(
                    "Lat: " + mCurrentLocation.getLatitude() + ", " +
                            "Lng: " + mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()
            );

            mapDrawLocation(new LatLng(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()));

            // giving a blink animation on TextView
            txtLocationResult.setAlpha(0);
            txtLocationResult.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(300);

            // location last updated time
            txtUpdatedOn.setText("Last updated on: " + mLastUpdateTime);
        }

        toggleButtons();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean("is_requesting_updates", mRequestingLocationUpdates);
        outState.putParcelable("last_known_location", mCurrentLocation);
        outState.putString("last_updated_on", mLastUpdateTime);

    }

    private void toggleButtons() {
        if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            btnStartUpdates.setEnabled(false);
            btnStopUpdates.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            btnStartUpdates.setEnabled(true);
            btnStopUpdates.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Starting location updates
     * Check whether location settings are satisfied and then
     * location updates will be requested
     */
    private void startLocationUpdates() {
        mSettingsClient
                .checkLocationSettings(mLocationSettingsRequest)
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
                    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "All location settings are satisfied.");

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Started location updates!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        //noinspection MissingPermission
                        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest,
                                mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());

                        updateLocationUI();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        int statusCode = ((ApiException) e).getStatusCode();
                        switch (statusCode) {
                            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                                Log.i(TAG, "Location settings are not satisfied. Attempting to upgrade " +
                                        "location settings ");
                                try {
                                    // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the
                                    // result in onActivityResult().
                                    ResolvableApiException rae = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                                    rae.startResolutionForResult(MapsActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sie) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "PendingIntent unable to execute request.");
                                }
                                break;
                            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                                String errorMessage = "Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be " +
                                        "fixed here. Fix in Settings.";
                                Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);

                                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        updateLocationUI();
                    }
                });
    }


    public void startLocationButtonClick() {
        // Requesting ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION using Dexter library
        Dexter.withActivity(this)
                .withPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                        mRequestingLocationUpdates = true;
                        startLocationUpdates();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {
                        if (response.isPermanentlyDenied()) {
                            // open device settings when the permission is
                            // denied permanently
                            openSettings();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {
                        token.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                }).check();
    }


    public void stopLocationButtonClick() {
        mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;
        stopLocationUpdates();
    }

    public void stopLocationUpdates() {
        // Removing location updates
        mFusedLocationClient
                .removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location updates stopped!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        toggleButtons();
                    }
                });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            // Check for the integer request code originally supplied to startResolutionForResult().
            case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Log.e(TAG, "User agreed to make required location settings changes.");
                        // Nothing to do. startLocationupdates() gets called in onResume again.
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Log.e(TAG, "User chose not to make required location settings changes.");
                        mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void openSettings() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(
                Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package",
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, null);
        intent.setData(uri);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Resuming location updates depending on button state and
        // allowed permissions
        if (mRequestingLocationUpdates && checkPermissions()) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }

        updateLocationUI();
    }

    private boolean checkPermissions() {
        int permissionState = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        return permissionState == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            // pausing location updates
            stopLocationUpdates();
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_maps.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity"
        map:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_panel"
        map:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        map:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/location_result"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Lat: 0.0, Lng: 0.0"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            map:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/updated_on"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Last updated on: "
            map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            map:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/location_result"
            />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_start_location_updates"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="START LOCATION"
                map:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/updated_on"
                map:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                map:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_stop_location_updates"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_stop_location_updates"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:text="STOP LOCATION"
                map:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/updated_on"
                map:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_start_location_updates"
                map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                map:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                />



        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Check Java code here

Comment: alright, thank you, i'll try it right away

Comment: hey i have a problem, the map showing in emulator, but it's not showing in my phone

Answer (score 1):

I Think this will help you. First see the package name is same you register on [console](https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_android_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_ANDROID&r=6A:18:BC:36:53:83:8A:2B:E4:B4:00:00:DC:D4:F8:D9:C9:A1:EA:CE%3Bcom.orbitalsonic.googlemapproject)

**build.gradle**

```
  // google map services
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.1'
    // location play services
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
    // dexter runtime permissions
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0'
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

**Kotlin MapsActivity.kt**

```
import android.Manifest
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentSender
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.Location
import android.net.Uri
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Looper
import android.provider.Settings
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResolvableApiException
import com.google.android.gms.location.*
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.*
import com.karumi.dexter.BuildConfig
import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionDeniedResponse
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionGrantedResponse
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.single.PermissionListener
import java.text.DateFormat
import java.util.*

class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    // location last updated time
    private var mLastUpdateTime: String? = null

    // location updates interval - 10sec
    private val UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS: Long = 10000

    // fastest updates interval - 5 sec
    // location updates will be received if another app is requesting the locations
    // than your app can handle
    private val FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS: Long = 3000

    private val REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 100

    private val TAG = "MainActivity"

    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap

    // bunch of location related apis
    private var mFusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient? = null
    private var mSettingsClient: SettingsClient? = null
    private var mLocationRequest: LocationRequest? = null
    private var mLocationSettingsRequest: LocationSettingsRequest? = null
    private var mLocationCallback: LocationCallback? = null
    private var mCurrentLocation: Location? = null

    // boolean flag to toggle the ui
    private var mRequestingLocationUpdates: Boolean? = null

    private lateinit var txtLocationResult: TextView
    private lateinit var txtUpdatedOn: TextView
    private lateinit var btnStartUpdates: Button
    private lateinit var btnStopUpdates: Button

    private var marker:MarkerOptions? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

        // initialize the necessary libraries
        initViews()
        initValues()
        onClickMethod()

        // restore the values from saved instance state
        restoreValuesFromBundle(savedInstanceState)
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap


        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        val islamabad = LatLng(33.684422, 73.047882)
        mMap.setMinZoomPreference(15.0f)
        mMap.setMaxZoomPreference(20.0f)
        marker?.position(islamabad)
        mMap.addMarker(marker!!)
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(islamabad, 17F))


    }

    private fun mapDrawLocation(loc:LatLng){

        mMap.clear()

        marker?.position(loc)
        mMap.addMarker(marker!!)
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 17F))


    }


    private fun initViews(){
        txtLocationResult = findViewById(R.id.location_result)
        txtUpdatedOn = findViewById(R.id.updated_on)
        btnStartUpdates = findViewById(R.id.btn_start_location_updates)
        btnStopUpdates = findViewById(R.id.btn_stop_location_updates)
    }

    private fun initValues() {
        marker = MarkerOptions()
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        mSettingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this)
        mLocationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult)
                // location is received
                mCurrentLocation = locationResult.lastLocation
                mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(Date())
                updateLocationUI()
            }
        }
        mRequestingLocationUpdates = false
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create().apply {
            interval = UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS
            fastestInterval = FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS
            priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
            isWaitForAccurateLocation = true
        }

        val builder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
        builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest!!)
        mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build()
    }

    private fun onClickMethod(){
        btnStartUpdates.setOnClickListener {
            startLocationButtonClick()
        }
        btnStopUpdates.setOnClickListener {
            stopLocationButtonClick()
        }

    }

    /**
     * Restoring values from saved instance state
     */
    private fun restoreValuesFromBundle(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("is_requesting_updates")) {
                mRequestingLocationUpdates = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("is_requesting_updates")
            }
            if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("last_known_location")) {
                mCurrentLocation = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("last_known_location")
            }
            if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("last_updated_on")) {
                mLastUpdateTime = savedInstanceState.getString("last_updated_on")
            }
        }
        updateLocationUI()
    }


    /**
     * Update the UI displaying the location data
     * and toggling the buttons
     */
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private fun updateLocationUI() {
        if (mCurrentLocation != null) {
            txtLocationResult.text = "Lat: " + mCurrentLocation!!.latitude + ", " +
                    "Lng: " + mCurrentLocation!!.longitude

            mapDrawLocation(LatLng(mCurrentLocation!!.latitude, mCurrentLocation!!.longitude))

            // giving a blink animation on TextView
            txtLocationResult.alpha = 0f
            txtLocationResult.animate().alpha(1f).duration = 300

            // location last updated time
            txtUpdatedOn.text = "Last updated on: $mLastUpdateTime"
        }
        toggleButtons()
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        outState.putBoolean("is_requesting_updates", (mRequestingLocationUpdates)!!)
        outState.putParcelable("last_known_location", mCurrentLocation)
        outState.putString("last_updated_on", mLastUpdateTime)
    }

    private fun toggleButtons() {
        if ((mRequestingLocationUpdates)!!) {
            btnStartUpdates.isEnabled = false
            btnStopUpdates.isEnabled = true
        } else {
            btnStartUpdates.isEnabled = true
            btnStopUpdates.isEnabled = false
        }
    }

    /**
     * Starting location updates
     * Check whether location settings are satisfied and then
     * location updates will be requested
     */
    private fun startLocationUpdates() {
        mSettingsClient
            ?.checkLocationSettings(mLocationSettingsRequest!!)
            ?.addOnSuccessListener(this) {
                Log.i(TAG, "All location settings are satisfied.")
                showMessage("Started location updates!")

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                }
                mFusedLocationClient!!.requestLocationUpdates(
                    mLocationRequest!!,
                    mLocationCallback!!, Looper.myLooper()!!
                )
                updateLocationUI()
            }
            ?.addOnFailureListener(this) { e ->
                val statusCode = (e as ApiException).statusCode
                when (statusCode) {
                    LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED -> {
                        Log.i(
                            TAG,
                            "Location settings are not satisfied. Attempting to upgrade " +
                                    "location settings "
                        )
                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the
                            // result in onActivityResult().
                            val rae = e as ResolvableApiException
                            rae.startResolutionForResult(
                                this,
                                REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS
                            )
                        } catch (sie: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                            Log.i(
                                TAG,
                                "PendingIntent unable to execute request."
                            )
                        }
                    }
                    LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE -> {
                        val errorMessage = "Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be " +
                                "fixed here. Fix in Settings."
                        Log.e(TAG, errorMessage)
                    }
                }
                updateLocationUI()
            }
    }



    private fun startLocationButtonClick() {
        // Requesting ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION using Dexter library
        Dexter.withActivity(this)
            .withPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            .withListener(object : PermissionListener {
                override fun onPermissionGranted(response: PermissionGrantedResponse?) {
                    mRequestingLocationUpdates = true
                    startLocationUpdates()
                }

                override fun onPermissionDenied(response: PermissionDeniedResponse) {
                    if (response.isPermanentlyDenied) {
                        // open device settings when the permission is
                        // denied permanently
                        openSettings()
                    }
                }

                override fun onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(
                    permission: PermissionRequest?,
                    token: PermissionToken
                ) {
                    token.continuePermissionRequest()
                }
            }).check()
    }

    private fun stopLocationButtonClick() {
        mRequestingLocationUpdates = false
        stopLocationUpdates()
    }

    private fun stopLocationUpdates() {
        // Removing location updates
        mFusedLocationClient
            ?.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback!!)
            ?.addOnCompleteListener(this) {
                showMessage("Location updates stopped!")
                toggleButtons()
            }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        when (requestCode) {
            REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS -> when (resultCode) {
                RESULT_OK -> Log.e(
                    TAG,
                    "User agreed to make required location settings changes."
                )
                RESULT_CANCELED -> {
                    Log.e(
                        TAG,
                        "User chose not to make required location settings changes."
                    )
                    mRequestingLocationUpdates = false
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        // Resuming location updates depending on button state and
        // allowed permissions
        if ((mRequestingLocationUpdates)!! && checkPermissions()) {
            startLocationUpdates()
        }
        updateLocationUI()
    }

    private fun checkPermissions(): Boolean {
        val permissionState = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        )
        return permissionState == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }


    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        if ((mRequestingLocationUpdates)!!) {
            // pausing location updates
            stopLocationUpdates()
        }
    }

    private fun openSettings() {
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.action = Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS
        val uri = Uri.fromParts(
            "package",
            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, null
        )
        intent.data = uri
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    private fun showMessage(message:String){
        Toast.makeText(this,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

}
```

**activity_maps.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity"
        map:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_panel"
        map:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        map:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/location_result"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Lat: 0.0, Lng: 0.0"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            map:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/updated_on"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Last updated on: "
            map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            map:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/location_result"
            />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_start_location_updates"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="START LOCATION"
                map:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/updated_on"
                map:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                map:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_stop_location_updates"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_stop_location_updates"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:text="STOP LOCATION"
                map:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/updated_on"
                map:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_start_location_updates"
                map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                map:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                />



        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: i'll try it, but is there java for it?

Comment: Sorry bro i made it in Kotlin

Comment: if it helps you accept my answer and give upvote

Comment: i hope i can, but first idk and don't use kotlin, second i need longclick marker to mark the map myself, not marking my current location. im just gonna upvote for now

Comment: I'm using it in my current project, I share it with you I think it will help you. thanks for upvote

Comment: yeah, it helpful, but not at what i expected, thank you for sharing tho, im gonna try to decompile it and rebuild the activity with my java, i'll add update soon

Comment: if you are facing problem to convert kotlin to java I will help you

Comment: I will write a code in java for you

Comment: it is very complicated when i decompile it in my android studio, if you can write it in java it will be really helpful, thank you

Comment: it's lunch time here i will edit my answer with java code after lunch

Comment: ok thank you so much, even if you edit it into java i still have to edit my longclick to add marker on the map on my own.

Comment: check my new answer with java i can not eddit this answer because stackoverfllow body limit is 30000